# Multi-step SMS error response

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile

We are trying to send multi-step vote/survey SMS.
We have created steps like these:
**Step    Type                   KeyWord     Next KeyWord**
1       Outbound-automation      none         STEP1;
2       Survey Y/N               STEP1        STEP2;
3       Send email               STEP2        none;

We have recieved the first SMS and have responded 'STEP1'
Then we have recieved the second SMS and have responded 'STEP2 Y'
Then we have recieved a SMS like "Sorry, this is not the correct response"

Could you tell us what are we doing wrong?

Thank you

**UPDATED**

The steps we followed are:
1 - we copied the example of http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/mobileconnect_use_cases/creating_a_survey_with_multiple_questions/
2 - we created an automation to start the proccess https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1EBHQJZR2PRcTZRUmdwLU11cjQ/edit?usp=sharing
3 - this automation sent the first outbound SMS https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1EBHQJZR2PRNENKV2pYX2RRaEk/edit?usp=sharing. The next keyword is "SURVEY"
4 - we have created the next survey SMS: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1EBHQJZR2PRSWVtSl81ZEpRbWc/edit?usp=sharing. The keyword is "SURVEY" and the next keyword is "RETURN"
We activated the automation an we recieved the message and we sent "SURVEY".
We recieved they survey SMS and we sent "RETURN Y"
We recieved the mesaage "Ther was an error processing you message" or "Sorry, but that´s not the correct answer"

Comment: Can you add more tags to narrow down the technology you are using e.g. is the exacttarget?

Comment: Yes we are using ExactTarget, sorry

Comment: Could you add some screen shots of how you have set this up?

Comment: Hello. We show you the steps I followed:

Comment: 1 - We have copied the example in http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/mobileconnect_use_cases/creating_a_survey_with_multiple_questions/

Answer (score 0):

The issue exists with your use of the next keyword.  MobileConnect uses the next keyword feature to determine which conversation you would like to direct the subscriber to after the current conversation is completed.  In the case of the survey template, the current conversation is not completed until the client has responded yes or no AND has received the response message.  When you set the keyword for the survey to 'SURVEY', MobileConnect is looking for 'SURVEY Y' or 'SURVEY N' in response.  It is not looking for the next keyword.  This is what's causing you to receive an error message.  I would suggest discarding the next keyword technique and following the steps below.

1. Create an outbound message (can be an automation) that says prompts the user to text 'RETURN' if they would like to take a survey.  You can set the next keyword to 'RETURN' if you wish.  It will not change the outcome if the subscriber responds 'RETURN'.
2. Create a survey message with the keyword set to 'RETURN' and leave the Next Keyword as a blank value.  Set the call to action as an External Source and the Survey Type as Yes/No. Set the Correct Answer to Yes.  Add your question "Would you like to return your item?" to the Outbound Message field.  Your text in the "Correct" Answer Response Message (RETURN Y) should direct the subscriber to text 'EMAIL youremail@email.com' to receive an email.  The text in the "Incorrect" Answer Response Message (RETURN N) should end the conversation with the subscriber.
3. Set up a send email message with the keyword set to 'EMAIL' and the call to action set to External Source.  This will send the client an email if they respond 'EMAIL youremail.com' to the last message of the survey conversation.